# Iterate into childs if variable still null

Tags: c#, iteration, treenode

I have a foreach method like this:

```
 TreeNode selectedNode = null;

 foreach (TreeNode tn in allNodes)
                {
                    if (selectedNode != null) continue;
                    var designNodes = tn.Nodes;


                    foreach (TreeNode item in designNodes)
                    {
                        if (item.Tag.ToString().Split('|')[0].Equals(designKey.ToString()))
                        {
                            selectedNode = item;
                            continue;
                        };
                        if (selectedNode is null)
                        {
                            foreach (TreeNode child in item.Nodes)
                            {
                                if (child.Tag != null && child.Tag.ToString().Split('|')[0].Equals(designKey.ToString()))
                                {
                                    selectedNode = child;
                                    continue;
                                }
                                if (selectedNode is null)
                                {
                                    foreach (TreeNode lastLevel in child.Nodes)
                                    {
                                        if (lastLevel.Tag != null && lastLevel.Tag.ToString().Split('|')[0].Equals(designKey.ToString()))
                                        {
                                            selectedNode = lastLevel;
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
```

First it iterates into TreeNode parent and assign variable `selectedNode`, if it does not found results (`selectedNode` still null)  it look childs of parent, and if it still null it look at childs of child.

Code it's working but it's too dificult to read, there is a best way to implement this iteration?

Comment: `if (selectedNode is null)` should be `if (selectedNode == null)`

Comment: Sorry, I update my question @RufusL

Comment: Shouldn't the `continue;` lines be `break;` instead? It seems like those are where you've found the correct match. Why continue? Also, is the purpose here to find the first node that meets the `Tag == designKey` condition? Or something else?

Comment: Yes if it assign lastDesign variable I use continue to break and it should finish assignation @RufusL

Comment: `continue` doesn't break, though...it just skips the rest of that iteration and then continues the loop. `break` will break out of the loop. Can you please define specifically what the code is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for here is a **breadth-first search**, where you first search all the children, then each child's children, etc, until you find a match.

For this type of searching we want to use a `Queue`, which is "first in - first out" (as opposed to a stack, which is "last in - first out"). This way we can `Enqueue` the root `TreeNode` items into the queue, then in a loop we `Dequeue` each item one at a time, check if it's valid, return it if it is, and if it isn't we `Enqueue` it's children. This ensures that we always check the parents before the children.

I've made this method a little more flexible as well by allowing the client to pass in a `validator` function that will be used to validate a `TreeNode`. This way we can re-use the method for doing breadth-first searching on any criteria we wish (we just pass to it a method that takes in a `TreeNode` and returns a `bool` that is `true` if the validation succeeds for that node):

```
private static TreeNode GetFirstMatch(TreeNodeCollection allNodes, 
    Func<TreeNode, bool> validator)
{
    if (allNodes == null) return null;

    // Initialize a Queue with all the root nodes
    var nodeQueue = new Queue<TreeNode>(allNodes.OfType<TreeNode>());

    // Use a queue for a breadth-first search
    while (nodeQueue.Any())
    {
        // Remove the next item
        var current = nodeQueue.Dequeue();

        // Return it if it passes our validation
        if (validator.Invoke(current)) return current;

        // Add it's children to the end of the queue
        foreach (TreeNode child in current.Nodes)
        {
            nodeQueue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }

    // If we didn't find any matches, return null
    return null;
}
```

In use we can just pass the `Nodes` property of our `TreeView` control to the method, along with the validation function (in this example I'm passing a lambda expression for the validation function):

```
TreeNode firstMatch = GetFirstMatch(treeView1.Nodes,
    node => node.Tag.ToString().Split('|')[0].Equals(designKey.ToString()));
```